# Installing gems on node heroku projects

Tags: ruby, node.js, heroku, rubygems, compass-sass

I'm writing a node app on heroku, and the app requires a gem, [compass](http://compass-style.org) to be installed, for [node-compass](https://github.com/nathggns/node-compass).

However, I can't seem to work out how you install gems in a node application on heroku. I have a Gemfile, which looks like so.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'compass'
```

Have you managed to do this successfully before?

Comment: I have a similar question here and it has the above answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465342/installing-gems-on-node-heroku-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an official reply from Heroku for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143977/install-a-gem-to-node-project-on-heroku):

> You would need to use the heroku multi buildpack in order to have both the Ruby buildpack and the Node buildpack: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a Gemfile, you need a buildpack and a Gemfile.lock. I wrote up how I got this working in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073828/180500) to a slightly different question, but I think it should answer this question too.