# Install a gem to node project on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, rubygems

I would like to install a gem to my node project, which is hosted on Heroku. More specifically I would like to use Sass with Compass, and Compass is only available as a gem. There are projects that wrap this gem for node, but all of them require the gem.

Is there a way to do this?

There's already this topic ([Installing gems on node heroku projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465342/installing-gems-on-node-heroku-projects)), but it hasn't received any replies.

Comment: Are you using node.js with modules, or ruby with gems? :)

Comment: npm-based modules. It is specifically for only this compass problem that we require compass, which is only distributed as a gem. There are node wrappers, but all of them use the gem as their basis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing gems on node heroku projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465342/installing-gems-on-node-heroku-projects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a reply from Heroku.

"*You would need to use the heroku multi buildpack in order to have both the Ruby buildpack and the Node buildpack:
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi*"