# NPM doesn't install module dependencies when deploying a Grunt app to heroku

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, gruntjs

I'v made a static single page site using grunt. I'm now trying to deploy it to heroku using the [heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt](https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt) for node grunt.

Below is a pic of my root directory:

[image: project root directory image]

Here's my [Gruntfile](https://gist.github.com/callumflack/8038483) [package.json](https://gist.github.com/callumflack/8038464):

`Procfile`:

```
web: node index.html
```

When I run `$ git push heroku master` it gets to the `Gruntfile` and fails:

```
-----> Found Gruntfile, running grunt heroku:production task
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
```

The above errors proceed to list all local NPM modules as not found. If I list all loadNpmTasks instead of using "load-grunt-tasks", I get the exact same error.

When I `$ heroku logs` I get:

```
Starting process with command `node web.js`
Error: Cannot find module '/app/web.js'
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone passing by here, I wasn't able to solve the problem. This is where I got to:

In my Gruntfile, I moved npm modules from devDependencies to dependencies. Heroku was then able to install these dependencies.

However, when Heroku ran the tasks, it stops at the haml task w/ error "You need to have Ruby and Haml installed and in your PATH for this task to work". Adding ruby & haml to the Gruntfile as engines did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is that maybe Heroku installs your `devDependencies` first, tries to run Grunt, but since it didn't install `load-grunt-tasks` yet, you don't get the `grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-uglify' );` line (which `load-grunt-tasks` does for you), and thus Grunt can't find the package.

Can you try changing your `Gruntfile` to explicitly list out all npm modules using the `grunt.loadNpmTasks()` method?

**EDIT:**

Just remembered another thing I had to do:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

(Obviously replacing `myapp` with your Heroku app name.)

This makes Heroku allow user set environment variables and then sets your server to `production`. Try that, and set your `dependencies` and `devDependencies` as you had them originally (just to see if it works).

Comment: Thanks but no dice on this method. However, I checked 'heroku logs' and found no mention of modules not installing on heroku and instead this:

    "Starting process with command `node web.js`"
    "Error: Cannot find module '/app/web.js'". Perhaps it's that I haven't written heroku Procfile properly?

Comment: Could be, although it's a pretty small file. :) Mine is just one line: `web: node app/app.js`

Comment: I also wonder if you should try adding your grunt modules to `dependencies` and not just `devDependencies`... I mean, you shouldn't have to... and I don't, but maybe just to see if it works?

Comment: That is it I reckon. I don't like that I have to do it that way. Haven't seen this in any of my googling (I'm not a coder!). This time I got almost to a full gruntfile compilation. Got a new error for the haml task, but that's just that I've not got Ruby and Haml installed in the project.

Comment: by the way, my Procfile used "web: node index.html" and that seems to work.

Comment: Well, glad you got further. Try the two lines in my edit above, you never know...

Comment: OK, this doesn't work. The gruntfile on heroku stops at the haml task w/ error "You need to have Ruby and Haml installed and in your PATH for this task to work". Tho I had added ruby & haml to the package.json for this test. This maybe a new error but of the same type it's another "load npm modules" problem. So I guess I don't understand. Of course I have ruby & haml globally on my local setup. Also, I did add the heroku "labs:enable" and "config:set" when I added the heroku-node-grunt buildpack.

Comment: Ouch... yeah, this is a complicated build for Heroku. I haven't tried to get it to install Ruby before in addition to Node. I can see there be all sorts of potential issues. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Cheers, appreciate your responses. I've iced this method for the time being. Hard to believe no-one else has not flagged a problem running grunt-haml to heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I am coming pretty late to the game here but I have used a couple methods and thought I would share.

## Option 1: Get Heroku to Build

This is not my favorite method because it can take a long time but here it is anyway.

Heroku runs `npm install --production` when it receives your pushed changes. This only installs the production dependencies.

You don't have to change your environment variables to install your dev dependencies. `npm install` has a [`--dev` switch](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#dev) to allow you to do that.

```
npm install --dev
```

Heroku provides an article on how you can [customize your build](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process). Essentially, you can run the above command as a `postinstall` script in your package.json.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "postinstall": "npm install --dev && grunt build"
}
```

I think this is cleaner than putting dev dependencies in my production section or changing the environment variables back and forth to get my dependencies to build.

Also, I don't use a Procfile. Heroku can run your application by calling `npm start` (at least it can now almost two years after the OP). So as long as you provide that script (as seen above) Heroku should be able to start your app.

As far as your ruby dependency, I haven't attempted to install a ruby gem in my node apps on Heroku but [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143977/install-a-gem-to-node-project-on-heroku) suggests that you use [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi).

## Option 2: Deploy Your Dependencies

Some argue that having Heroku build your application is bad form. They suggest that you should push up all of your dependencies. If you are like me and hate the idea of checking in your `node_modules` directory then you could create a new branch where you force add the `node_modules` directory and then deploy that branch. In git this looks like:

```
git checkout -b deploy
git add -f node_modules/
git commit -m "heroku deploy"
git push heroku --force deploy:master
git checkout master
git branch -D deploy
```

You could obviously make this into a script so that you don't have to type that every time.

## Option 3: Do It All Yourself

This is my new favorite way to deploy. Heroku has added support for [slug deploys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler). The previous link is a good read and I highly recommend it. I do this in my automated build from [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/). I have some custom scripts to tar my app and push the slug to Heroku and its fast.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with Heroku not installing all of my dependencies, while I had no issue locally. I fixed it by running

```
heroku config:set USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
```

into the path, where I deployed my project from. This instructs Heroku to install your dependencies using npm install instead of npm ci, which is the default! From Heroku dev center:

"Heroku uses the lockfiles, either the package-lock.json or yarn.lock, to install the expected dependency tree, so be sure to check those files into git to ensure the same dependency versions across environments. If you are using npm, Heroku will use npm ci to set up the build environment."